# How to assign an object property value as a key in the same object?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to assign a value of an object property as a key in the same object?

Like this:

```
var o = {}
o = {
    a: 111,
    b: 222,
    [o.a]: 'Bingo'
};
```

This code is wrong because the result is

`{a: 111, b: 222, undefined: 'Bingo'}`

Comment: At the point `[o.a]` is evaluated, `o = {}`. `o.a` isn't `111` until after the whole assignment completes.

Comment: Just do `a: 'Bingo'`, it will overwrite the first `a`'s value

Comment: @ArslanSohailBano That is different to what OP is trying to do, they want to add `111: 'Bingo'`, not `a: 'Bingo'`.

Comment: Oh, true my bad!

Comment: @jonrsharpe It looks like this would work - o[o.a]='Bingo'

Comment: Of course, because that would be _after_ the first assignment when `o.a` is `111`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps

```js
var o = {
    a: 111,
    b: 222
};
o[o.a] = 'Bingo';

console.log (o);
```

Alternatively, store 111 in a variable first

```js
var x = 111;
var o = {
    a: x,
    b: 222,
    [x]: 'Bingo'
};

console.log (o);
```